# Saídas inesperadas do código de listagem de séries de um usuário

Tags: python

O código que eu fiz que pergunta ao usuário as séries que ele acompanha e possui alguns problemas:

**1º problema**: o contador da linha `serie = str (input("Digite a sua {}a série favorita: ".format(i+1)))` **não atualiza para 2a, 3a, 4a** e fica sempre assim:

> **1º loop**:
>
> `Digite a sua 1a série favorita:`
>
> **2º loop**
>
> `Digite a sua 1a série favorita:`
>
> `...`

**2º problema**: Gostaria de adicionar uma condição abaixo do `if serie != '':` **que mostre uma mensagem que o usuário não pode digitar um único caractere da série** mas não sei como fazer isso.

**3º problema**: Existe um `for` no final do código que lista todos as séries que o usuário digitou**, mas não está do jeito que eu queria.

> **Do jeito que eu queria**
>
> `1a serie favorita: The Punisher`
>
> `2a serie favorita: O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina`
>
> `...`
>
> **Do jeito que se encontra**
>
> `: ['', 'The Punisher', 'O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina', ...]`
>
> `The Punisher: ['', 'The Punisher', 'O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina', ...]`
>
> `O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina: ['', 'The Punisher', 'O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina', ...]`
>
> `...`

O código que fiz:

```
nome = ""
series = ['']
i = 0
while nome == "":
    nome = str (input("Digite seu nome: "))

print ("{} quero lembrar que não é permitido digitar apenas uma letra".format(nome))
print ("Deseja responder a pergunta? ")
resposta = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0]

while resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's':
    serie = str (input("Digite a sua {}a série favorita: ".format(i+1)))

    if serie != '':
        print ("Nome da série: {}".format(serie))

    series.append(serie)

    print ("Deseja digitar mais alguma série {}?".format(nome))
    resposta = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0]

if resposta == 'N' or resposta == 'n':
    print ("{} Bye!".format(nome))

for i in series:
    print ("{}: {}".format(i,series))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro problema (não atualiza o número da série) acontece porque você não está incrementando o contador `i` dentro do loop.

O segundo problema é resolvido verificando-se o tamanho da string digitada, através da função [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

O terceiro problema (mostrar as séries) acontece por causa deste *loop*:

```
for i in series:
    print("{}: {}".format(i, series))
```

A variável `series` é uma lista que contém todas as séries. Ao fazer `for i in series`, a cada iteração do *loop*, a variável `i` contém o nome de uma das séries. Mas você imprime o nome (a variável `i`) e toda a lista (a variável `series`), por isso a saída está do jeito que você indicou.

Outros detalhes para arrumar:

- a variável `series` começa como uma lista contendo uma string vazia (`series = ['']`). Mas não há motivo para isso, basta atribuir o valor `[]` para que a lista comece vazia
- a função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, não é necessário usar `str(input(...))`
- se quer iterar pelos elementos da lista juntamente com o respectivo índice, basta usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

O código fica assim:

```
nome = ''
while not nome:
    nome = input("Digite seu nome: ").strip()

print("{}, quero lembrar que não é permitido digitar apenas uma letra".format(nome))
print("Deseja responder a pergunta? ")
resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ").strip()[0]

i = 1
series = []
while resposta.lower() == 's':
    while True:
        serie = input("Digite a sua {}a série favorita: ".format(i)).strip()
        if len(serie) <= 1:
            print('Nome deve ter mais de uma letra')
        else:
            break # nome OK, sai do while True

    # o while True acima já garante que o nome estará preenchido
    print("Nome da série: {}".format(serie))
    series.append(serie)
    i += 1

    print("Deseja digitar mais alguma série, {}?".format(nome))
    resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ").strip()[0]

if resposta.lower() == 'n':
    print("{}, Bye!".format(nome))

for i, serie in enumerate(series):
    print("{}: {}".format(i + 1, serie))
```

Outros detalhes:

- usei [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para remover os espaços do início e fim das strings retornadas por `input` (não é estritamente necessário, use se quiser)
- o *loop* `while True` já garante que o nome da série deve estar preenchido, então não preciso testar o nome antes de imprimi-lo
- para verificar a opção, eu uso `resposta.lower() == 's'` - pois [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) transforma a string em minúsculas. Mas se quiser, também pode fazer `while resposta in ('S', 's'):`.
- `while not nome` [é o mesmo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) que `while nome == ""`

---

Você também pode quebrar cada parte do código em funções (uma para ler o nome da série, outra para as opções, etc), assim o código fica um pouco mais organizado:

```
def ler_opcao(mensagem, nome=None):
    if nome:
        print('{}, {}? '.format(mensagem, nome))
    else:
        print('{}? '.format(mensagem))
    # já retorna a opção como letra minúscula
    return input("S - Sim | N - Não: ").strip()[0].lower()


def ler_nome_serie(i):
    while True:
        serie = input("Digite a sua {}a série favorita: ".format(i)).strip()
        if len(serie) <= 1:
            print('Nome deve ter mais de uma letra')
        else:
            return serie  # nome OK, retorna o nome da série


nome = ''
while not nome:
    nome = input("Digite seu nome: ").strip()

print("{}, quero lembrar que não é permitido digitar apenas uma letra".format(nome))
resposta = ler_opcao("Deseja responder a pergunta")

i = 1
series = []
while resposta == 's':
    serie = ler_nome_serie(i)
    print("Nome da série: {}".format(serie))
    series.append(serie)
    i += 1

    resposta = ler_opcao("Deseja digitar mais alguma série", nome)

if resposta == 'n':
    print("{}, Bye!".format(nome))

for i, serie in enumerate(series):
    print("{}: {}".format(i + 1, serie))
```

Outro detalhe é o `if resposta == 'n':`. O `while` só verifica se a opção é `s`. Então se a pessoa digitar, por exemplo, `x`, ele também sai do `while`, mas depois não entra no `if` (pois não foi digitado `n`). Se quiser que sempre imprima a mensagem "Bye", basta retirar o `if`.

Comment: Algumas coisas que você explicou será de grande ajuda, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Para o primeiro problema vc pode fazer o seguinte:
`i = i + 1` antes de colocar dentro do `Format` e depois usar o `Format(i)`, porque da forma que vc está fazendo ele não está incrementando o `i`, o código só está apresentando a soma de `i` (que é 0) com 1.

O segundo problema pode ser resolvido com a função `len(sua string)` dentro do `if` (essa função devolve a quantidade de itens de um conjunto, que pode ser string, lista, etc).

O terceiro problema ocorre porque no `for` a cada iteração vc exibe o vetor de séries por completo, a variável `i` do `for` (que deveria ter outro nome, que não fosse usado antes) é um item do vetor, no seu caso o vetor está assim `[' ', 'The Punisher', 'O Mundo Sombrio de Sabrina']`, e o `for` está exibindo o item atual e depois todos os itens a cada iteração.

Pra vc resolver, na declaração do vetor `series` tire as aspas de dentro dos `[]`, dentro do `for` use o `i` (com outro nome) no lugar de séries e no lugar do `i` use um contador também dentro do `for`.